# Why give me this error when I open web app in browser through IIS Express in visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

I am new to ASP.net and try to perform CRUD operation but My page didn't run on browser?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, it should be

```
<connectionStrings>
```